# Windows batch: call more than one command in a FOR loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible in Windows batch file to call more than one command in a **single** `FOR` loop? Let's say for example I want to print the file name and after delete it:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /r %%X IN (*.txt) DO (ECHO %%X DEL %%X)
REM the line above is invalid syntax.
```

I know in this case I could solve it by doing two distinct FOR loops: one for showing the name and one for deleting the file, but is it possible to do it in one loop only?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
FOR /r %%X IN (*) DO (ECHO %%X & DEL %%X)
```

Comment: Actually, I think the parentheses are unnecessary. `for %i in (1 2 3) do echo %i & echo foo` prints what I'd expect: "1", "foo", "2", "foo", "3", "foo" (on separate lines).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `&&` rather than `&`?

Comment: @jww `&&` will fail if the first command fails, `&` will execute the second command regardless.

Comment: If this solution makes a syntax error for you, check out if you got an unescaped paren between the `DO`-parens. You may escape them by appending a `^` to them.

Answer (score 232):

Using `&` is fine for short commands, but that single line can get very long very quick. When that happens, switch to multi-line syntax.

```
FOR /r %%X IN (*.txt) DO (
    ECHO %%X
    DEL %%X
)
```

Placement of `(` and `)` matters. The round brackets after `DO` must be placed on the same line, otherwise the batch file will be incorrect.

See `if /?|find /V ""` for details.

Comment: This solution looks clean and readable. I would also warn any programmer who uses this solution that the round bracket after the `DO` must NOT be placed next line otherwise it brakes the batch file. In code when I write a for loop I commonly place the curly bracket `{` next line.

Comment: Also -- be wary if any of your nested commands have brackets in (for example, something like "echo Something something (something else)" EDIT: ah, see bk1e's answer :)

Comment: The key is: The round brackets after DO must be placed on the same line, otherwise the batch file will be incorrect!

Answer (score 36):

SilverSkin and Anders are both correct. You can use parentheses to execute multiple commands. However, you have to make sure that the commands themselves (and their parameters) do not contain parentheses. `cmd` greedily searches for the first closing parenthesis, instead of handling nested sets of parentheses gracefully. This may cause the rest of the command line to fail to parse, or it may cause some of the parentheses to get passed to the commands (e.g. `DEL myfile.txt)`).

A workaround for this is to split the body of the loop into a separate function. Note that you probably need to jump around the function body to avoid "falling through" into it.

```
FOR /r %%X IN (*.txt) DO CALL :loopbody %%X
REM Don't "fall through" to :loopbody.
GOTO :EOF

:loopbody
ECHO %1
DEL %1
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: While we are on the topic, %X is never correct when dealing with filenames, always use "%~X" (In your example here, you could get away with using %* in the subfunction probably)

Comment: That's a really good point. A good example of a path that demonstrates both problems is `C:\Program Files (x86)`.